# When should you use XS?

Tags: perl, perl-xs

I am writing up a talk on XS and I need to know when the community thinks it is proper to reach for XS.

Comment: Is your talk/presentation available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of at least three reasons to use XS:

1. You have a C library you want to access in Perl 5
2. You have a block of code that is provably slowing down your program and it would be faster if written in C
3. You need access to something only available in XS

Reason 1 is obvious and should need no explaination.

When you really need reason 2 is less obvious.  Often you are better off looking at how the code is structured.  You should only invoke reason 2 if you have [profiled your code](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) and have a [benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) and [test suite](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) to prove that the XS code is faster and correct.

Reason 3 is a dangerous reason.  It is rare that you actually need to look into Perl's guts to do something, but there is at least [one valid case](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Readonly-XS/XS.pm).

Comment: It would be great if you could also cover the advantages/disadvantages of using Inline::C vs. pure XS.

Comment: Yes, a comparison would be great. One more entry to the wishlist: what sort of things can be done only with XS, and what can be done only with Inline::C.

Comment: Inline::C is just a wrapper around XS.  It makes it very easy to call out to C, but has the disadvantage that you need the same C compiler used to build your perl.  In general, you should only use Inline::C to build the XS code for you, then take that code and strip out Inline::C.  That's the best of both worlds.

Comment: @hexcoder As far as I know, there is nothing that XS does with Perl's guts that `Inline::C` can't.  The major difference is when the code gets compiled (at build time vs run time) which has a major effect on how easy it is to deploy code written with `Inline::C`.  Ah, the war stories I could, and will, tell about `Inline::C` deployments.

Comment: @frezik, the compiler requirements are the same for XS and Inline::C.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, There's also permission issues, since Inline::C actually needs to create files. Inline::C is easier to work with, so it can be useful as a prototyping tool.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, (3) is not rare at all. Examples: Pretty much anything in Scalar::Util, modifying Perl's syntax (without using a source filter), adding magic other than tie to variables, creating a PerlIO layer, etc, etc

Comment: @ikegami Good point, but when you compare the number of uses for 1 and 2, the number of sane cases of 3 are very small.

Answer (score 3):

In a few cases, better memory management is another reason for using XS. For example, if you have a very large block of objects of some similar type, this can be managed more efficiently through XS. `KinoSearch` uses this for tokens, for example, where start and end offsets in a large string can be managed more effectively through XS than as a huge pool of scalars. `PDL` also has a memory management aspect to it, as well as speed.

There are proposals to integrate some of this approach into core Perl in the long term, initially because it offers a chance to make sharing data in threading better: see: http://openparallel.com/2011/07/05/a-new-hope-for-efficient-safe-data-sharing-between-threads-in-perl/.

Comment: This is a good point, I think it falls under reason 2, but my reason 2 was too narrowly defined.  I think reason 2 should probably be something like "To make more efficient use of the computer's resources".

Comment: @Chas. Owens, agreed. You'd typically use different tools to assess it, and on 32-bit systems might be forced sooner to adopt this strategy because memory has a hard limit, but is another resource issue